# Question on derivability in terms of a 2-rule calculus

Tags: logic, notation

I apologize for this post's title.  I know it is awful, but I cannot come up with anything better.

This question is about Exercise 4.6 of the book [*Mathematical Logic*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/OhJXzgEACAAJ?hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkudmv9uP2AhVGTt8KHcHhDroQ7_IDegQIERAC), as shown at the end of the screenshot<sup>1</sup> below:

> [image]

Even with the very helpful [answer to an earlier question on this very same exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88071/13675), ***I still don't understand what this exercise is asking!***

First, I don't understand this rather crucial bit in the first question:

> [image]

If I understand correctly, the rules given so far for generating terms and formulas do not provide any way to create a *multi-character* term or formula that begins with a variable.  So I don't know what $xt$ could possibly refer to (other than a non-term, non-formula string in the set $\mathbb{A}_{S}^*$).

Then there is the conspicuously wide separation between the preceding comma and the $xt$.  Did something get left out?

Of course, (b) is also incomprehensible, given that I cannot make any sense whatsoever of (a).  Therefore, I would appreciate a clarification of (b) as well.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Typesetting is an important aspect of this question, and therefore I decided to use a screenshot of the original, rather than attempt to reproduce it with my very deficient MathJax skills.</sup>

Comment: The first rule produces the string "x x" from nowhere (here the space is only for readibility: space is not a symbol of the language).

Comment: The second rule applied to the above result will produce "x fx", and the property is satisfied: the rightmost expression is a term with x free. And so on.

Comment: IMO the space is only for readibility: no special meaning. The result is "variable x followed by a term with x free".

Comment: Regarding "space" what is the difference between $\lnot p$ and $\lnot \ p$?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I brought up the issue of whitespace only because I couldn't make any sense at all of "$\;\;\;\;xt$", and I was looking for any clue I could find.  In other words, I was "grasping at straws."  That said, both $\neg p$ and $\neg\;p$ *look* like terms, but I can think of no addition of whitespace that can turn $xt$ into a term.  I am still a bit puzzled by "$xt$", "$x\;\;\;\;t$", etc., because none of them conforms to any of the constructs (namely terms and formulas) that the authors have taken great pains to delimit as meaningful within the formal system under discussion.

Comment: As per my comments, xt is not a term. It is an expression meaning the function $x \to t$ where x occurs free in t. Havin sai that, you are satisfied with the answer below and this is enough :-)

Comment: Yes, I get that.  What rattles me is that, on the one hand, the authors have been *extremely* careful, bordering on pedantry, when it comes to specifying what strings are at all valid in their presentation, but on the other hand, they just start using something like "$xt$", which does not conform to anything that they have yet allowed, without even an *informal* definition of what this string represents.  This sharp contrast in attitudes is disorienting, and rather off-putting in a textbook on formal mathematics.

Comment: For LaTeX, use "`\quad`" for that length of whitespace, and "`\ `" for a normal space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your right, there should be a white space, in between $xt$, as Brian says the white space can be interpreted as "is a variable of". It’s probably a typesetting issue.

Answer (score 1):

For part (b) of Ex.4.6., we have to write rules for managing the cases, made of a premise (maybe empty) and a conclusion.

The rules for the two base cases are rules without premise:

$\dfrac { }{t_1=t_2 \ \ \ \{ t_1=t_2 \} }$

And similar for the second form of atomic formula.

The rules for connectives have premise. For the negation sign the premise will be:

$\dfrac { \varphi \ \ \{ \text { list of subformulas } \} }{ \lnot \varphi \ \ \ \ \{ \lnot \varphi, \text { list } \} }$.

What the rules define is a function: $\varphi \to \text {Sub}(\varphi)$.

Having this in mind, it must be clear that the notation used by the author: $\varphi \text {Sub}(\varphi)$ - with or without space - does not represent a formula.

For the same reason, the calculus of part (a) does not produce a (wrogly written) term $xt$ but the function $x \to t$, where $x$ occurs free in $t$.